# How to add audio elements and video elements for gstreamer with qtdemux

Tags: command-line, gstreamer

I want to stream a youtube video using gstreamer. So I gave the following command in command line :

```
gst-launch-0.10 souphttpsrc location=$(/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -g -f 18 i4jTHhXuKLA) ! typefind ! qtdemux name=demux demux.audio_00 ! multiqueue ! aacparse ! faad ! audioconvert ! pulsesink demux.video_00 ! multiqueue ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! ffdec_h264 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=1024,height=768 ! sdlvideosink
```

After that, a window is opened with no video or audio playing.
I got the following output on command line :

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
```

So I tried the following command with audio elements alone :

```
gst-launch-0.10 souphttpsrc location=$(/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -g -f 18 i4jTHhXuKLA) ! typefind ! qtdemux name=demux demux.audio_00 ! multiqueue ! aacparse ! faad ! audioconvert ! pulsesink
```

Its fine, I am able to hear the audio output.

Similarly When I gave the following command with video elements alone :

```
gst-launch-0.10 souphttpsrc location=$(/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -g -f 18 i4jTHhXuKLA) ! typefind ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! multiqueue ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! ffdec_h264 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=1024,height=768 ! sdlvideosink
```

I am able to see the video playing without audio.

Please Help me where I went wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing with `playbin2`:

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=$(/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -g -f 18 i4jTHhXuKLA)
```

For information, this is the pipeline created by playbin2 (Use "View Image" from your browser to get it full sized):

[image]

If you need to render the video stream at 1024x768, try the following pipeline instead:

```
gst-launch-0.10 uridecodebin name=dec uri=$(/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -g -f 18 i4jTHhXuKLA)  ! queue ! autoaudiosink dec. ! queue  ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=1024,height=768 ! autovideosink
```

Both tested OK on 14.04.

Comment: But with playbin2, Video scaling is not possible.
I want to do scaling so that it exactly fits to my display. MY display size is 1024 * 768.

Comment: @bharathkumarreddybojja I've updated my answer with a videoscale after decodebin2, please have look

Comment: What ever you have said is working very fine on PC.
But when I am trying to run the same in iMX6 SD Board with ubuntu version 12.04, I have got the following observations:
1) The audio and video both are coming.
2) But the video is strucking in between with many frames being dropped.
3) It is saying like There may be a timestamping problem or this computer is too slow. A lot of buffers are being dropped.
4) But the audio is playing smooth.
So what might the problem?

Comment: @bharathkumarreddybojja did you try the playbin2 command? does it drop frames too?

Comment: playbin2 does not support video scale. So I am using decodebin2. It is dropping frames

Comment: @bharathkumarreddybojja I was asking to run playbin2 (even if no scaled as you wish) to just know if it drops frames too. If not we should look at the pipeline it built more closely (see picture from my post).

Comment: Ya I checked with playbin2. It is not dropping frames. But I want scaling to be done

Comment: @bharathkumarreddybojja: Using `uridecodebin` allows some buffering while the pipeline is PREROLLING. Please try the updated command.

Comment: Yaa I checked it in the iMX6 Board. Even with this, a lot of buffers are being dropped !!